# Create a dictionary with two columns of a panda Dataframe depending on another column values

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I would like to create a dictionary with two columns of a panda Dataframe depending on another column values.

I have a dataframe as below:

```
       a    b  c
0  brand    F  0
1  brand    G  1
2   seat  yes  1
3   seat   no  0
```

I would like to create dictionaries like:

```
brand = {'F':0,'G':1}
seat = {'no':0,'yes':1}
```

Trying this does not give me the results.

```
dic = {}
for x,y in zip(b.values, c.values):
    dic.setdefault(y,[]).append(x)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you be more specific than "does not give me the results"?

Comment: And please provide a reproducible input, not an image of the data

Answer (score 2):

A modification of your approach would be:

```
dic = {}
for a, b, c in zip(df['a'], df['b'], df['c']):
    dic.setdefault(a, {})[b] = c
```

The [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) equivalent:

```
dic = (df.set_index('b').groupby('a')['c']
         .agg(lambda g: g.to_dict())
         .to_dict()
      )
```

Output `dic`:

```
{'brand': {'F': 0, 'G': 1},
 'seat': {'yes': 1, 'no': 0}}
```

Comment: `.agg` using `.to_dict`.  nice, i didn't think of that.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to programmatically assign variables names from values in the columns. An easy solution is a dictionary with dictionaries as the values.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
  'a': ['brand', 'brand', 'seat', 'seat'],
  'b': ['F', 'G', 'yes', 'no'],
  'c': [0, 1, 1, 0]
})

dic = {}
for k, g in df.groupby('a'):
    dic[k] = dict(zip(*g[['b','c']].values.T))

dic
# returns:
{'brand': {'F': 0, 'G': 1}, 'seat': {'yes': 1, 'no': 0}}
```

Comment: Or  `dic[k] = dict(zip(g['b'], g['c']))` ;)